# How to setup Symfony2 Bundles independently with related Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to figure out a smart way to implement my bundles with following requirements:

1. I have a Bundle with logic named `LogicABundle`
2. I have a Bundle with common things as design and Menus called
   `AppBundle`
3. I have another Bundle with logic `LogicBBundle` with some entities
   related to `LogicABundle` entities

I know want to be able to "deploy" two applications from this setup:

1. Application one uses the `LogicABundle` and `AppBundle`
2. The second one uses `LogicABundle`, `LogicBBundle` and `AppBundle`

The issue is, that for the second application I need to relate some Entities from `LogicABundle` to `LogicBBundle`, which causes the first "deploy" option to brake, if I just have an entity in `LogicABundle` pointing to `LogicBBundle`.

Is there a smart solution to deploy these two different applications independently?
Here is an example in order to make it easier to understand:
namespace My\LogicABundle\Entity\Game;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * My\LogicABundle\Entity\Game
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 */
class Game
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     *
     * @var Message
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\LogicBBundle\Entity\Message", inversedBy="games")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="messag_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */

    private $message; 
}
```

I want to be able to use the Game class in my standalone application only with LogicABundle, and in my second application I need the game Entity with message relation.

Comment: You can extend a bundle from other in Symfony

Comment: If I would use BundleInheritance I would need a ExtendedLogicABundle, which inherits from LogicABundle, where I extend Entities with relation to LogicBBundle. Besides, the part of correctly overwriting Entities is not yet documented : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html This would also mean that I need an additional Bundle for the related Entities for evey existing Bundle. E.g. I have an UserBundle, which will also have relations to LogicBBundle, in this setup I would also need an ExtendedUserBundle. This approach does not appeal that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but I have the same problem and I just found that : http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Hope not to late ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git (or SVN or another source countrol tool) I would recommend to create two separate Symfony2 applications (each in its on repository). Also, every bundle gets its own repository and I would use Composer to set up the dependencies correctly and then install the bundles (LogicABundle, LogicBBundle, AppBundle) as vendors.

**Update:** Since the different bundles need different entities, one way is to specify the base entity in the bundle that does only need the base entity and extend the entity in the other bundle with additional relations (see [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)).

For example, define `EntityA` in LogicABundle and define `EntityA2` in LogicBBundle where `EntityA2` extends `EntityA` and adds additional relations to the entity.

**Update:** Since you do not have provided additional information why you need to do this, I can only guess now, but one additional idea would be to simply use the same entities in both bundles. The logic in `LogicABundle` would simply ignore the additional relations. I think that is what most developers would do in your situation.

Consider, for example, bundles that provide common functionality like FOSUserBundle. The bundle defines some models, but not every application that uses FOSUserBundle has to use every field of the entities (in a application I am currently developing I completely ignore the groups functionality of FOSUserBundle).

Please provider further information if it is possible to use a common entity class and ignore these additional relations.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that I need 2 versions of LogicABundle, the one with Entity relations to LogicBBundle and one without. I was just wondering wether there is a "clean" solution within Symfony2.

Comment: When the entities are different in the both bundles you can't share them. You can either place them in the same bundle, but I would prefer separating them into different bundles. For example, CoreABundle contains the entities for LogicABundle and CoreBBundle the entities for LogicBBundle

Comment: This is what I thought would be the best solution, but then I thought about my "additional" UserBundle, which in scenario one needs to have a relationship to EntityA and in Scenario 2 a relationship to EntityA2. This will lead to the fact that LogicBBundle will have almost ALL entities within. And then I also need to prevent the creation of a table for EntityA, because only EntityA2 should be used.

Comment: Maybe you can think of some way to decouple the two bundles or a least the entities. Even if you have two applications, you could use the same entities in both of them (e.g., store them in a CoreBundle) and just ignore the additional relationship in one of the applications.

Comment: I am not sure which further information could clarify this issue. I think the proposed approach is the only one I could try. But it's not a really clean solution. I tried to simplify my case, but of course there are more dependencies. I think LogicBBundle will extend LogicABundle and where I need additional relations I will create LogicBEntity extending LogicAEntity and the same for controllers where I need to adjust the controller logic. It will depend on how much my LogicBBundle really alters the parts of LogicABundle. Entities will definately need to be extended due to addition relations.